# Photoshop Help With a Map Design Please!

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have photoshop on my macbook and would like to know how I can design a map like this one referenced. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out how to make the lines for the map that look so simple. How to create these lines for roads with open ended boxes? I know how to curve lines but how do I create them with the open ends like this one? Also how do I get the insides of the roads to be white and the edges of the lines to be a different color? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks. [image]

Comment: You don't use Photoshop. You use Illustrator or some other *vector* application.

Comment: Do you have access to Illustrator? It would be better in a vector format as @Scott indicated but it can certainly be done in Photoshop as well if you have no alternative. Also while showing us the map is nice, show us what you've tried. As it stands this is very broad and probably a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks Scott. @Ryan yes I'm downloading illustrator as we speak now. I wish I could post what I've done so but the farthest I've gotten is trying to use the pen to draw straight lines then curve them to match. But that's where I stopped though after not being able to make those lines open at the end. Not to mention the curves were not uniform! I'm sure it has to do with my lack of knowledge of  photoshop, and after much googling on my own here's where I ended up cause I new I was going to need someones help who actually knows what they're doing lol. Thanks.

Comment: Inkscape is a free vector app if you don't want to pay for Illustrator when the trial expires. If you are going to learn something from scratch. You may want to start with Inkscape if the Adobe subscription isn't enticing to you. Curves, open paths, multiple strokes, overlapping strokes, will all be easier in a vector app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Illustrator Help With a Map Design Please!](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/54913/illustrator-help-with-a-map-design-please)

Answer (score 1):

I advise that you use illustrator for this task.

You can easily draw the lines using the pen tool.

1) use the pen tool (P) and start drawing some paths. Once you're done with a road you can click on the black mouse (V) to stop/deselect the current path. You can change the colors by selecting the boxes next to the width stroke option.

[image: stroke options]

2) Re-select the path using the black mouse tool (V). Change the stroke to something wide like 13 pt.

[image: draw lines with the pen tool]

3) Select the paths with the mouse tool (V), copy them (CTRL + C) and then paste in back (CTRL + B). Then change the stroke width and color.

[image: copy paths and paste in back]

4) I created a new layer below the top roads (The 3 roads I created in the first image). Draw more paths with the pen tool (P) and and repeat step 3 (To easily select the bottom roads, just lock the top layer).

[image: more roads]

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop and illustrator are excellent software capable to really really great things. But for your requirement to create this line map, you could try an open source tool like [PENCIL](http://pencil.evolus.vn/). Using basic flowchart tool box, you should be able to create this map. They have mac version too. I have attached a little portion of your map created in Pencil. Once you are done creating your map, you can use photoshop for any fine-tuning. [image: sample using pencil]

Comment: I now have illustrator on my computer. Would you let me know how to go about creating what you just did on illustrator or anyone whos willing to help for that matter?

Comment: David, the sample that i did was done using PENCIL...link is in the answer

Comment: The sample that i put..was done using PENCIL. Link is in the answer. Its straightforward and simple. Please check it out.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try downloading PENCIL then. But in the above referenced picture I uploaded. The lines are straight on FWY 41 but it looks like a elbow is connecting the straight lines into a bend. Can I do that in PENCIL?

Comment: Yes, there is an option to use freehand curves for non straight lines. And remember you can always take you image from pencil to Photoshop (as PNG) for fine tuning and enhancements.

Comment: Ok, im messing with the program now. but what about open ended boxes?

Comment: Use lines to create open ended boxes

Comment: ok. now how do I fine tune these curves? im using the free line tool but how do I make the curve exactly how I want it?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above, Illustrator should be able to do a better job for this and could save a lot of time and make it flexible for future as well. If you only have Photoshop to use for the moment, there could be a few ways to create the open end boxes like in the picture; by adding a small rectangle box (or any layer) that matches the background just on top of the end of the road (this layer being 1-up from the road layer), alternatively, you could also rasterise the layer (road layer) and cut a portion out of it at the end, thus giving the same effect (this might be rather time-consuming and should need some fine-tuning, but should hopefully do the trick):
Hopefully this helps!

[image: lines hidden]

[image]

Comment: Hi Simo, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: Thanks @Simo. Yes I have illustrator installed now on my mac. it's pretty overwhelming for me compared to photoshop so I'm still learning the basics. I really like what you did above but what about the curved part of the freeway? How do I make sure when I curve two lines that they are the same width (symmetrical)? I notice in illustrator you can use the curve line tool. But in the above referenced picture I uploaded. The lines are straight on FWY 41 but it looks like a elbow is connecting the straight lines into a bend. How do I do that?

Comment: Hi @David, you can make use of grids and guides.  Guides can be  dragged from the ruler pressing right-click and dragging them to the stage. Showing Grids may help to make the lines similar width. You can create turns, curves, etc. by using the Pen tool. I did a quick google search, and you may find this useful: http://photoshopcafe.com/tutorials/pen/pen.htm There should be loads of more tips and tutorials for using the Pen tool. Pen tool will be also very useful in Illustrator. I'll add a few more results to the answer above after using the pen tool with grids/guides